# Are there two triangles per line on the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm learning about the unit circle in trig, and I have a question.

Let's say we were to have a line on the circle. Take this crude drawing, for example:

[image: 2]

This is a triangle on the unit circle. But isn't there another triangle that can be drawn?

[image: 1]

The reason I'm asking this is because I was trying to solve a problem that asked the sine and cosine of a 330 degree angle, and the answer tried to state that it could be "simplified" in a way to a 30 degree angle, and not a 60 degree angle.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may represent the sine and cosine of a $330$-degree angle using a $60$-degree angle, by swapping the roles of sine and cosine and negating if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 330$^\circ$ angle is equivalent to a -30$^\circ$ angle.  "Negative" angles are measured clockwise from the positive x-axis while "positive" angles are measured counterclockwise from the positive x-axis.  That's just convention but angles on the unit circle are measured that way and not from the y-axis.

The 30$^\circ$ angle the problem is referring to is called a "reference angle", basically the first angle around the circle on which that kind of triangle is formed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean radius by “line”.

Yes, if you have some radius at some angle with the horizontal, the two triangles that can be drawn is the triangle with the radius, sine, and x-axis line segments, and the other is the triange with the radius, cosine, and y-axis segment.

When we visualize the sines and cosines on a unit circle, we typically think of $a$ as the sine segment, $b$ as the cosine segment, and $r$ as the radius (hypotenuse).

[[image: Image of unit circle with <span class=]$a$, $b$, and $r$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mFC1.png)

Hence we only really need one triangle to visualize both $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

About the angle, a $330^\circ$ angle is actually equivalent to a $-30^\circ$ angle. While we measure positive angles counterclockwise from the vertical, negative angles are measured clockwise.

We can get there by subtracting a full rotation $360^\circ$ off from $330^\circ$. Then, the value of $\sin(-30^\circ)$ will just be $-\sin(30^\circ)$ which you can find. Similar can be done for cosine.

We can usually always simplify angles $>270^\circ$ by subtracting off a full rotation.